# Overloading Present for multiple arguments

Tags: fortran, overloading

Is it possible to overload Present(arg) so I can have
Present(arg1,arg2,...) to mean

```
If (Present (arg1) .And. Present (arg2) .And. ... )
```

I am trying to do it but it feels as though it is not so straightforward to do.

Comment: Sounds like a good job for the preprocessor.

Comment: `if (all( [ present(arg1), present(arg2), present(arg3) ]))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly the answer is: no, you cannot.  You can indeed create a generic identifier called `present` and have a new specific name:

```
module mod
  interface present
    module procedure present_two_real
  end interface
contains
  logical function present_real_real(a,b)
    ..
  end function
end module
```

However, inside that function we know that the dummy arguments must be `optional`.  If they weren't it wouldn't be legal to pass optional actual arguments in a procedure to that function: see Fortran 2008 12.5.2.12.

When we look at how we different two procedures must be to be able to have the same generic identifier (12.4.3.4.5) we have constraint C1215.  It's this constraint with the `optional` requirement in the new specific name which makes us unable to do what you want.  Note that the argument in the specific procedure `present` isn't optional.

That doesn't mean you can't have a generic `present_all`, of course.  You'll need a specific procedure for each combination of argument characteristics you want, though (as my choice of specific name above suggests).  [Recall that template's are not in Fortran's style.]  Further, you'll still need to handle the requirement to distinguish the specific implementations.  It all sounds like a bit too much work, really.

Comment: I was following you until you mentioned a generic `present_all`.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering whether I should explain more.  Rather than having `present(arg1, arg2)` offer `present_all(arg1, arg2)`.  This has the additional advantage of making it clear that the truth corresponds to all arguments present: you may want also `present_any(arg1, arg2)` (although that's of limited utility).

Comment: Which means that if I want to check for three arguments I got to write another function with a different name which I would not be able to overload using Interface.

Comment: Yes (so `present_all` wasn't a good choice of name for me), it all gets messy quickly.  It comes down to the fact that the arguments have to be optional and how this messes up the disambiguation.

Comment: Correct. Two functions become ambiguous if they only differ in the number of optional arguments.